# How can I limit registration on ASP.NET starter site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

ASP.NET newbie question.  I'm starting with ASP.NET's Starter Site that comes with a set of built-in registration, authentication pages, and membership DB.

Now my question is, how can I restrict registration to my site?  This site is for a patient practice and only patients need access.

I have read about roles, but assigning roles means the user has already registered.  I don't want users created in the DB without being authorized either by email or other credentials that an admin will enter prior to registration.

Please let me know the best way to achieve this modification to the starter site template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest is to simply comment out the actions in the `Account` controller that related to registration. The anyone trying to go to the registration page get's a 404.

Comment: So you're suggesting to manually register users? Yeah, I could do that but I was hoping for something more elegant that still allows users to choose a password without exposing it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it as you wanted to completely remove any ability to register so that an admin would have to do it for them.

Answer (score 0):

As `siva.k` mentioned in a comment you can remove the registration process from public access, that means users will not be able to register by themselves, an administrator must be in charge of creating users. This implies that you will need user security roles...at least if you don't want your patients to have access to administrative areas such as user management.

Another approach which will require a bit of more effort is to "send email invitations to your patients". Someone perhaps an administrator simply need to enter (at least) an email address and the system would trigger an email inviting the user to register. Obviously, this will require to have a registration page/view to be publicly accessible, but protected to only users who have been sent out an invitation. Determining whether the user is genuine or not it's quite simple. At the time the system sends out the invitation, it logs an entry in a database record...say an email address, a random unique code and perhaps an expiry date to validate the invitation. The random unique code could be whatever you want but must be unique within the system and most importantly NON-SEQUENTIAL (as in incremental integers or something like that). This code can be sent to the invited patient in the form of a url query string parameter, this url is the link to the registration page. Then, the registration page will extract this code from the url, validate it against the database record, deletes the record and then serves the registration page. If the validation fails you can easily respond with a 403 or 404 http code.

As I said, it requires a bit of effort on your side but you could make it a robust solution you can report on.

Comment: You could also register a user with a random password and then use the email verification token to email them and ask them to complete a signup that would also let them set their password. I think it'd be a little less wheel invention since the verification token system exists already.